# How to fix relization of classes using abstraction?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an abstract class:

```
export abstract class Tree<T extends TreeChildrenNodes<T>> {
     abstract initialize(source: T, treeControl: NestedTreeControl<T>): void;
     toggle() {
      // TODO
     }
   
     expand() {
      // TODO
     }

     collapse() {
      // TODO
     }
}
```

Then I use the concrete implemenmtations:

```
class TreeLayer extends Tree<NodeTree> {
   initialize(source: T, treeControl: NestedTreeControl<T>) { 
       // TODO
   }
}

 class TreeMap extends Tree<NodeTree> {
    initialize(source: T, treeControl: NestedTreeControl<T>) { 
       // TODO
   }
  
    /* Own method
    showNodeInf(node) {
       // TODO
    }
 }
```

I use DI to inject the concrete implementation to component:

```
export class TreeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(private tree: Tree<TreeNode>) {} // Component does not know about which imlementation I passed
}
```

Problem is template can contains additional DOM elements, for example:

```
<span (click)="showNodeInf(node)">Show node info</span>
```

So inside component handler:

```
 public showNodeInf(node): void {
    this.tree.showNodeInf(node); //Here is problem
 }
```

Problem is that inside component I dont now the concrete type of Tree, it can be injected `TreeLayer` or `TreeMap`. Therefore I can not use this:

```
public showNodeInf(node): void {
    this.tree.showNodeInf(node); //Here is problem
}
```

Because the method `showNodeInf(node)` is present obly if was injected `TreeMap` instance.

Important: The component acts as mediator.

Comment: What template are you talking about? And yes, if the `TreeComponent` should work with arbitrary `tree` implementations, it must not use methods that are not part of the interface. It should not be responsible for doing `showNodeInf` stuff at all.

Comment: I am talking about HTNL template with DOM

Comment: You mean HTML? And what does that have to do with your TypeScript class components? Are you using a framework? Where in your code are you interacting with the DOM?

Comment: I use Angular, so the component is as mediator iteracts with concrete implementation of Tree

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Updated answer

A better option is to join an interface with the optional methods with your abstract class, in this case you can have optional methods, and thus only call if they exist.

Just add the following interface before your abstract class:

```
interface Tree {
   showNodeInf?(node: NodeTree): void;
}
```

And call the method using optional chain:

```
public showNodeInf(node): void {
    this.tree.showNodeInf?.(node);
}
```

### Previous answer

For such use cases you can use the constructor name property and identify the object class name:

```
this.tree.constructor.name // Which should return TreeLayer or TreeMap
```

And then by casting the object you should be able to call the function specific to one object.

```
public showNodeInf(node): void {
    if (this.tree.constructor.name === 'TreeMap') {
        (this.tree as TreeMap).showNodeInf(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not good If there are a lot of concrete implementations.

Comment: I see, in this case I have an update answer that may suffice your needs.